# HAPROXY: multiple domains, multiple ports, multiple server

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have two domains (`abc.com`, `xyz.com`), four ports (`443`, `8080`, `80`, `3000`) and three servers (`10.147.19.1`, `10.147.19.2`, `10.147.19.4`).
I want to set up the Haproxy to achieve these type of routes:

```
abc.com:443     ---> 10.147.19.1:80
abc.com:8080    ---> 10.147.19.2:3000
xyz.com:443     ---> 10.147.19.1:80
xyz.com:8080    ---> 10.147.19.4:3000
```

From the docs, I can bind front end with Haproxy Maps. So I tried to bind port 443 with maps.

```
frontend port_443
        bind *:443
        use_backend %[req.hdr(host),lower,map_dom(/etc/haproxy/maps/port_443.map,be_default)]
```

Here is the map

```
# Domain    backend
  abc.com   be_1
  xyz.com   be_1
```

The question, how to define the backend with the right ports? Please help!